# How does ecrypt handles symlinks to unencrypted files?

Tags: 12.04, ecryptfs

I have a encrypted home directory, and I have some large files (VMs) that I store outside of my home directory in `/opt/jrg-stuff/VMs`.

How would ecryptfs handle a symlink to those files? Will it 'freak out' and try and encrypt them? Will it create multiple copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't try to encrypt them or anything.

Just do a normal symlink (like `ln -s /opt/jrg-stuff/ ~/MyVMs`) and it will be fine. It won't try and encrypt them (from what I see), it will just link them.